# Fail to parse date with time zone with Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to use Joda Time both for formatting DateTime objects to String and than parse these strings back to DateTime. But I am failing to so when the pattern includes z:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z");

    String dts = dtf.print(System.currentTimeMillis());

    System.out.println(dts);

    DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime(dts);
```

The above code is throwing exception when the parsing the String to DateTime takes occurred.

Do you have any idea?

Yosi

Comment: What's the exception?  What is the value of dts that gets printed?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498274/why-joda-datetimeformatter-cannot-parse-timezone-names-z

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
System.out.println(dt.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS z"));
```

Have a look in the [user guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

The Pattern is not correct, maybe try this one

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS'z" );
```

this worked for me