# MapperParsingException when re-indexing data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to re-index data to correct date formats, however, I am encountering a MapperParsingException when parsing a date field in the format  **'Thu Jan 01 02:00:00 SAST 1970'**. I used the dateOptionalTime mapping, which I guess is wrong.

None of the built in formats on the [Elasticsearch Date Format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) reference seems to fit the bill though. Is this something I must specifically customize or can a built in Date Format version be used?

**EDIT 1: mappings**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "users": {
            "properties": {
                "creationdate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "email": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "firstlogin": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "firstname": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lastloggedin": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "lastname": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lastprofileupdate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "userid": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "username": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    },
                    "copy_to": [
                        "username.raw"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you delete and re create indices after changing the mapping? Can you post your mapping?

Comment: Yes, I deleted it prior to changing the mapping and re-creating the index.

Comment: You should delete and recreate indices after you changed the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected you would need to use the [custom date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-date-format.html#custom).

Unfortunately though the above example uses [timezone names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498274/why-joda-datetimeformatter-cannot-parse-timezone-names-z) i.e "*z*" which is not supported by JODA.

If it is possible for you to change the format of time zone to use [zone id](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html)
you could use custom format as follows :

```
Example Date: "Thu Jan 10 02:00:00 Africa/Johannesburg 1970"    
lastloggedin" : {
                "type": "date",
                "format" : "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ y"              
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this mapping instead

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "users": {
            "properties": {
                "creationdate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "E MMM d H:m:s z Y"
                },
                "email": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "firstlogin": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "firstname": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lastloggedin": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "E MMM d H:m:s z Y"
                },
                "lastname": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lastprofileupdate": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "E MMM d H:m:s z Y"
                },
                "userid": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "username": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    },
                    "copy_to": [
                        "username.raw"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: timezone names are not supported by JODA

Comment: It's throwing an error as it can't handle the timezone (SAST..). It would probably be best to re-index from the source and ensure I import in a format that Joda can handle.