# Logstash: How to match the timezone ID 'CET' in a date filter pattern?

Tags: date, timezone, logstash, jodatime

In Logstash, I want to convert a string into a timestamp using the date filter. The string looks follows:

```
Fri Nov 05 06:24:28.651 CET 2021
```

I've tried the following pattern to no avail:

```
  date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS ZZZ yyyy"]
      locale => "en_US"
      timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
      target => "syslog_timestamp"
  }
```

This is confusing since [Logstash is said to use the Joda library](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-match) and Joda in turn says ['CET' is a legal timezone ID](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). I confirmed the results by testing the Jody library v2.10.13 directly in a Java application.

How to parse CET/CEST in the date filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [time zone names (z) cannot be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498274/why-joda-datetimeformatter-cannot-parse-timezone-names-z) and ZZZ still wouldn't match the daylight-saving variant 'CEST' according to Joda's documentation, I worked around this issue in Logstash by handling the timezone code as text and passing multiple patterns with the standard time zone and daylight-saving time zone to the filter:

```
match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 'CET' yyyy", "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 'CEST' yyyy"]
```